# (The process started from Chrome location /opt/Google/Chrome/Google-Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was using Selenium and was testing what it can do. But, when I followed a tutorial and did it, It gives me an error`(The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`. I looked up and found my Chrome was not in the default location. I am using Linux mint and Pycharm. I tried reinstalling Chrome. But, It did not work.